# react render message before loading new state

Tags: reactjs, state

I have this function in react to fetch some data from my backed and re-renders the sate. There is some processing going on in the backend so it takes some seconds to render the state.

Is there a way to render a loading message before the state renders?

```
 handleSpecies(e){
    console.log(e.target.text)
    let filteredSpecies = [];
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/films/search/'+ e.target.text).then(results => {
      if(results.ok){
        return results.json();
      }
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch');

    })
    .then(data => {
      filteredSpecies = data;
      this.setState({species:filteredSpecies})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    this.setState({ error: error.message } )
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div className="col-md-4">
        <div className="list-group">
        {

          this.state.species.map((species, i) => {
            return (
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item" key={i}>{species.name}</a>

            );
          })
        } 
      </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: The way I do it is I have an `is<SomeThing>Loading` flag that I toggle depending on what's happening, and then I either show the loading indicator or not. This doesn't not do exactly as you ask because technically I'm updating the state, but it could possibly fit your needs

Comment: I am updating the stae..or changing it. Sorry I am new and still trying to comprehend the state stuff. I think what you suggest might work,but where in my code should I put it?

Comment: Don't let things like that confuse you off the start. Just put it where you think you need it, and determine if it's a flexible solution that works for your needs. If I was looking at this tiny block of code, I'd just throw in a `this.setState({isSpeciesLoading: true})` before the fetch, and then a `this.setState({isSpeciesLoading: false})` after the fetch. (I'm not sure if that will cause a rendering error because you may be trying to update the state while a render is executing, but the message should be clear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing to remember is that having an `is<SomeThing>Loading` flag allows you to A) Have multiple loading indicators for each section of a page, and B) Allows explicit handling of errors, rendering, etc. It helps avoid all of the "well if the list is empty, maybe my API call didn't succeed" or other ambiguous scenarios.

Given only your code, here's what I would do

```
 handleSpecies(e){
   this.setState({ isSpeciesLoading : true })
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/films/search/'+ e.target.text).then(results => {
      if(results.ok){
        return results.json();
      }
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch');

    })
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({species:data, isSpeciesLoading : false})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    this.setState({ error: error.message, isSpeciesLoading : false } )
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div className="col-md-4">
        <div className="list-group">
        {this.state.isSpeciesLoading ? <div>Loading...</div>
        {
          !this.state.isSpeciesLoading &&
          this.state.species.map((species, i) => {
            return (
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item" key={i}>{species.name}</a>

            );
          })
        } 
      </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a ternary before maping the species: if species is empty or falsable, then print a message.

```
 <div className="col-md-4">
    <div className="list-group">
    {(!this.state.species || !this.state.species.length) ?
      this.state.species.map((species, i) => {
        return (
          <a href="#" className="list-group-item" key={i}>{species.name}</a>

        );
      }) : <p> Please wait </p>
    } 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually that doesn't seems to work for me. The please wait message stays up there forever and the state doesn't render. The initial state of this is all the species and when I click on a button it sets the state again with new species. I hope I am describing it well

Comment: Ok it doesn' t work because species is fulfilled at the initial state.

Just add a `isLoading` attribute in your state, initialized at false. At the beginning of `handleSpecies() {`, put it at true. Don't forget to put it at false in your fetch callback.

Then you juste have to replace my last ternary expression by `!this.state.isLoading`

Good luck.

Comment: What your solution doesn't help with is HTTP errors or other states of the application where data is loading. With this code, we have no idea if we ever executed a fetch or not

Answer (score 1):

Defining an `isLoading` state variable would be a nice solution for your problem.

You can set it to `true` just before firing the async request and set it to `false` when request is completed or failed.

Then you just have to conditional render your component based on the `isLoading` flag.

A code snippet demonstrating your problem is the following:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: false,
    species: '',
  }

  handleSpecies(e) {
    console.log(e.target.text)

    this.setState({isLoading: true});

    let filteredSpecies = [];
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/films/search/'+ e.target.text; 
    fetch(url)
      .then(results => {
        if(results.ok){
          return results.json();
        }
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch');
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          species: data,
          isLoading: false,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ 
          error: error.message,
          isLoading: false,
        });
      });
  }


  render() {
    const {
      isLoading,
      species,
    } = this.state;

    return (
       <div className="col-md-4">
          <div className="list-group">
            { 
              isLoading 
              ? <Loading/> 
              : species.map((specie, i) => <a href="#" className="list-group-item" key={i}> {specie.name} </a>)

            } 
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```